# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el día de una fecha y asignar el contenido de otro campo?

Tags: sql

estoy intentando asignar al día de una fecha el contenido de un campo entero, que está en la misma tabla, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE [prueba].[dbo].[tabla]
SET FECHA_INSERT = CAST(CAST(YEAR(FECHA_INSERT)*10000 + MONTH(FECHA_INSERT)*100 
+ (SELECT CAMPO FROM prueba..tabla) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DATE)
```

Pero me dice que el subquery devolvió más de un registro, ¿hay alguna manera en la que yo pueda hacer esto?

Comment: Es porque el subquery está devolviendo efectivamente más de un registro, para hacer la prueb ejecuta el subquery solo y observa. Lo que tú quieres hacer es que sume el campo de ese mismo registro? pon la subconsulta completa y pon la estructura de la tabla

Comment: No, no quiero eso, lo que quiero es que para cada registro de la tabla, se actualice el campo FECHA_INSERT, asignandole el valor de día, con el valor del otro campo, cuyo nombre es IDC que es de tipo INT

Comment: Entonces todos los CAST para qué son?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que estás haciendo la consulta a la misma tabla, basta con usar el nombre del campo en el set. MS SQL puede asignar el valor de un campo del mismo registro en otro campo. Algo así:

```
UPDATE [prueba].[dbo].[tabla]
SET FECHA_INSERT = CAST(CAST(YEAR(FECHA_INSERT)*10000 + MONTH(FECHA_INSERT)*100 + CAMPO AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Esta no es una forma elegante de hacerla, ya que sql tiene funciones que ya realizan esta operación.

Comment: ¿Cuál operación?

Comment: La función es Datefromparts

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar este código

```
UPDATE [prueba].[dbo].[tabla] SET FECHA_INSERT = datefromparts(year(fecha_insert),month(fecha_insert),day(campo))
```

Comment: saludos y gracias por apoyar pero se espera de las respuestas no solo el código, sino una explicación; de lo contrario se vería de baja calidad

Comment: Gracias por la observación, solo que no lo vi necesario porque en la respuesta de niche, expliqué el porqué de utilizar esta función, pero lo tomaré encuenta para próximas respuestas.

Comment: si pero eso fue un comentario en la respuesta de otro usuario, tu respuesta acá es independiente y los futuros usuarios que consulten deben encontrar fácil no solo el código si no el por que

Comment: Hola Martín, en vez de hacerlo en proximas respuestas, pulsa en [edit] para mejora esta. Todas las respuestas tienen que tener la máxima calidad posible. Y la explicacion es lo más necesario de todo. Un saludo